# No easy run button when using Java in VS Code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I am a software developer and am having a problem with Visual Studio Code while trying to run Java. When running other languages (such as python) there is a green triangular button on the top right that allows an easy way to run my code, however, when I trying running Java there arrow is not there and I have to manually select "Run Code" from the "Run" ribbon at the top of the screen. Is there any way that I could get the same green run button when using Java? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Visual Studio is not the first choice for Java devs, why don't you use Eclipse or IntelliJ? Or is it because VS is what your team uses, and you "must" use it too because if you don't, everyone will have a heart attack.

Comment: You did install the recommended Java Addons for VSCode, did you? I'm using VSCode for Java dev since years and the debugging support is quite good.

Answer (score 2):

Press crtl+F5 to run without debugging and F5 running with debugger.
You can use the integrated terminal for compiling and executing by using the `javac <filename>.java` for compiling and `java <filename>` for executing.

[Set your own key bindings.](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#:%7E:text=All%20keyboard%20shortcuts%20in%20VS,This%20will%20open%20your%20keybindings.)

[Preset shortcuts](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

Install **Java Extension Pack** in extension marketplace will solve your question, also you can install **Code Runner** which provides button for code running too.
[image]